# Upload Images to Firebase Storage and store a link in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am uploading an image to firebase and i want to store its url to database

My image gets uploaded in Firebase Storage and Name is stored in Firebase Database

But in ImageUrl "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@5ef6ed8" this kind of url get stored

what changes should i do to store correct url

Please provide full code

Here is my Upload_photos.java

```
package com.namandevloper.satyampublic;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Upload_Photos extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText name;
    private Button uploadbutton;
    private Uri imageuri;
    private StorageReference mStorageref;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseref;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload__photos);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        uploadbutton = findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        mStorageref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Upload Photos");
        mDatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Upload Photos");



        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openfilechooser();


            }
        });

        uploadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadfile();

            }
        });
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));

    }

    private void uploadfile() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        progressDialog.show();


        if (imageuri !=null){
            StorageReference  filereference  = mStorageref.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+
                    "."+getFileExtension(imageuri));

            filereference.putFile(imageuri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                            Toast.makeText(Upload_Photos.this, "Upload Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(name.getText().toString().trim(),taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()
                            .toString());
                            progressDialog.show();




                            String  uploadId = mDatabaseref.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseref.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();




                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded  " +(int)progress+"%");



                        }
                    });

        }else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select a Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





    }

    private void openfilechooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null &&
        data.getData()!=null){
            imageuri = data.getData();
           Picasso .get().load(imageuri).into(imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

this is my upload.java

```
package com.namandevloper.satyampublic;

      public class Upload {
        private String mName;
        private String mImageUrl;

        public Upload() {
            //empty constructor needed
        }

          public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
              if (name.trim().equals("")) {
                  name = "No Name";
              }

              mName = name;
              mImageUrl = imageUrl;
          }

          public String getName() {
              return mName;
          }

          public void setName(String name) {
              mName = name;
          }

          public String getImageUrl() {
              return mImageUrl;
          }

          public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
              mImageUrl = imageUrl;
          }
      }
```

This is my activity_upload__photos

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Upload_Photos">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Image to Upload"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="249dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/click" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"

        android:hint="Image Name" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_upload"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="Upload"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how my database looks

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7vfH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the listener to get the download uri from firebase storage. Use following code to do that. Read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url)

```
filereference.putFile(imageuri)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(Upload_Photos.this, "Upload Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                        Upload upload = new Upload(name.getText().toString().trim(),downloadUrl.toString());
                        progressDialog.show();
                        String  uploadId = mDatabaseref.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseref.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    })
    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded  " +(int)progress+"%");



        }
    });
```

Comment: When i use filepath it shows can not resolve symbol and when i use filereference it shows 2-3 errors at bottom. What should i do? Can you please send me the whole code after correcting it or can i please talk to you in-person?

Comment: @user9157668 pleae use updated code

Comment: Yes i used it but then everything below it gives me errors. Please put whole code please.

Comment: Please explain what error you get

Comment: The .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { gives error can not resolve method. Please can you talk to me on some other platform?

Comment: Please check i removed the semi colon from the answer. you also remove it because your using other async calls

Comment: Have a look at the code - https://imgur.com/Lxr2R5N